# Enable / Disable textbox based upon text entered - Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I enter text in tb1, tb2 disables ok, but when I remove all the text, I get a popup reporting tb1 is empty but tb2 doesn't enable again.

I have tried using enabled = true to no avail. Suspect have made a silly mistake but have looked at it for days and still don't get it!

```
function dataentering() {

            if (document.getElementById("<%=tb1.ClientID %>").value.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("<%=tb2.ClientID %>").disabled = true;

            } else {
                window.alert('tb1 is now empty');
                document.getElementById("<%=tb2.ClientID %>").disabled = false;

            }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLtGd/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine in JSFiddle, but if you're still facing the issue, you can try:-

```
if (document.getElementById("foo").value.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("bar").disabled = 'disabled';

    } else {
        window.alert('tb1 is now empty');
        document.getElementById("bar").removeAttribute("disabled");

    }
```

Because I've seen, in some browsers the disabled : true & disabled  : false doesn't work.

Comment: FANTASTIC !!! I have been testing in firefox and Chrome as project dictates but as your comment highlights my code works in IE. Your code works in all browsers.  a very big thank you !